# Changes to spacing inside floats

Tags: floats, sectioning, paragraphs

I have a two-column style, but sometimes I want to put some text across the whole page. An easy way to do this is inside one of the starred float environments. I am using table*.

However, I notice that when I put ordinary paragraph text and headings inside a table* (with no tabular), some spacing elements change. There is no longer any paragraph indentation and no space appears between paragraphs and headings.

Is there a list somewhere of which lengths are changed in the table* environment? How can I configure text inside table* to have the same spacing as my normal body text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

floats execute `\@parboxrestore` (like parbox) and `\@floatboxreset` which mostly does `\reset@font\normalsize` to normalize the fonts.

`\@parboxrestore` is:

```
\def\@arrayparboxrestore{%
  \let\if@nobreak\iffalse
  \let\if@noskipsec\iffalse
  \let\par\@@par
  \let\-\@dischyph
  \let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii
  \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@skip
  \everypar{}%
  \linewidth\hsize
  \@totalleftmargin\z@
  \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \@rightskip\z@skip
  \parfillskip\@flushglue \lineskip\normallineskip
  \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip
  \sloppy}
\def\@parboxrestore{\@arrayparboxrestore\let\\\@normalcr}
```

So mostly `\fussy` to undo `\sloppy` and setting `\parindent` and `\parskip` to whatever values are set by your document class will produce a standard setting.

or locally set `\let\@parboxrestore\relax` before your float so none of the above happens.

However for normal text spanning two columns it is usually better to use

```
\twocolumn[
 normal text spanning both columns here
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, David. I found this does exactly what I want:    \newenvironment{onecolumnfloat}[1][t]{%
    \let\@floatboxreset\relax%
    \let\@parboxrestore\relax%
    \begin{table*}[#1]\unskip}{\end{table*}}

Comment: \twocolumn[] is fine for simple text but there are limitations on what you can put as a parameter. Defining a new environment is more robust.

Comment: @MichaelDavis but the `[]` argument is a fixed unit, but a table is a float and normal paragraph text doesn't normally float. The only limitation (which applies to both) is that the text is a box so can not be longer than the page.

Comment: The paragraph I tried to float had some \verb text in it, which is illegal in the [] but allowed in the {onecolumnfloat} environment. The environment also allows having several paragraphs of text and even tables or figures so it's a bit more flexible.

Comment: @MichaelDavis oh details.. both of those are easily avoidable actually:-) (but it's fine: if the float doesn't float either by luck or because it's pinned with \clearpage then it will work well enough for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst} \usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{etoolbox} \BeforeBeginEnvironment{strip}{\setlength\stripsep{0pt}\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip \relax}}
\AtEndEnvironment{strip}{ \vspace{-\topsep}}
 \begin{document}

Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. text. Some text.
```

%
    \begin{strip}\parindent = 1em\par
      Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text.

```
  Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\end{strip}

Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. text. Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]